# Exists query with not equal running extremly slow

Tags: oracle

I am trying to modify a query that someone else wrote which is taking a really long time to run. The problem has to do with the <> portion of the exists query. Any idea how this can be changed to run quicker?

```
SELECT m.level4 center, cc.description, m.employeename, m.empno,
       TO_DATE (ct.tsdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') tsdate, ct.starttime, ct.endtime,
       ct.DURATION,
       NVL (DECODE (ct.paycode, ' ', 'REG', ct.paycode), 'REG') paycode,
       ct.titlecode, ct.costcenter, m.tsgroup
  FROM clairvia_text ct, MASTER m, costcenteroutbound cc
 WHERE ct.recordtype = '1'
   AND ct.empno = m.empno
   AND m.level4 = cc.center
   AND EXISTS (
          SELECT ct1.recordtype,ct1.empno,ct1.tsdate,ct1.processdate
            FROM clairvia_text ct1
           WHERE ct.recordtype = ct1.recordtype
             AND ct.empno = ct1.empno
             AND ct.tsdate = ct1.tsdate
             AND ct.processdate = ct1.processdate
             group by ct1.recordtype,ct1.empno,ct1.tsdate,ct1.processdate
             having count(*) < 2)
```

Comment: I have to think that using a `GROUP BY` would be a much easier way of determining whether duplicates with different IDs exist.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle can be finnicky with exists statements and subqueries. A couple of things to try:

1. Change the exists to an "in"
2. Change the exists to a group by statement with a "having count(1) > 1". This could even be changed into a join.

I'm assuming indexes are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [analytic function count](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) here to eliminate duplicated rows.

```
select * from ( 
    SELECT m.level4 center, cc.description, m.employeename, m.empno,
           TO_DATE (ct.tsdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') tsdate, ct.starttime, ct.endtime,
           ct.DURATION,
           NVL (DECODE (ct.paycode, ' ', 'REG', ct.paycode), 'REG') paycode,
           ct.titlecode, ct.costcenter, m.tsgroup,
           count(1) over (partition by ct.recordtype,ct.empno,ct.tsdate,ct.processdate
             order by null) cnt
      FROM clairvia_text ct, MASTER m, costcenteroutbound cc
     WHERE ct.recordtype = '1'
       AND ct.empno = m.empno
       AND m.level4 = cc.center
  ) where cnt=1
```

---

I do not have your structures and data, so I run similar queries with all_tab_cols and first query took ~500s on my laptop and second query ~2s.

```
-- slow test
select count(1)
  from all_tab_cols atc
    where exists (  
      select 1 
        from all_tab_cols atc1
        where atc1.column_name = atc.column_name
        group by column_name
        having count(1) = 1)

-- fast test
select count(1)
  from (
    select column_name, 
        count(1) over (partition by atc.column_name order by null) cnt
      from all_tab_cols atc
    )
  where cnt = 1
```